# How to get current user flow in apex

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, list, user

I am calling an apex class from a flow (in flow debugger) where I want to get the current user/starter of the flow. I tried to get the user with apex but get a system nulpointer exception. I also cannot debug the user in my debug logs. What am I missing see:

```
public class getCancelOptionsCurrentUser {
    @InvocableMethod(label = 'Get cancel options current user' description = 'Get amendment Cancel reasons')
    public static List<List<String>> getCancelOptionsMsPicklist() {
    String CancelOptions;
    List<String> lstCancelOptions = new List<String>();
        Id CurrUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
         system.debug('CurrUserId:'+ CurrUserId);
        try {
            CancelOptions = [SELECT Id, Reasons_Cancel__c from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()].get(0).Reasons_Cancel__c;
            system.debug('CancelOptions:'+ CancelOptions);
        } Catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug('Error Canceloptions current user: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
        if (String.isNotBlank(CancelOptions)) lstCancelOptions = CancelOptions.split(';');
        return new List<List<String>>{lstCancelOptions};
    }
}
```

Nulpointer Exception on line:

```
CancelOptions = [SELECT Id, Reasons_Cancel__c from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()].get(0).Reasons_Cancel__c;
```

Comment: why not just create a formula field in flow and in the resource use {!$User.Id}

Comment: @User6670  I need to get the "Reasons_Cancel__c" of the user in the apex class so thats why I want to get the current user in apex

Comment: i guess we can get that field too from formula

Comment: @User6670  I get where you are coming from. Since I want to use this in an managed package I dont want to have dependencies of fields directly in my flow. So thats why I want to get the user from apex.

Comment: Please edit your post to specify which line is throwing the null pointer exception.

Comment: @DavidCheng I added the line where the nullpointer happens.

Comment: Seems like I cant do = :UserInfo.getUserId() in the soql directly but need to do: = :CurrUserId

Comment: why the .get(0),i guess you are getting only one record

Comment: @User6670 2The current user only has 1 record with field "Reasons_Cancel__c"

Comment: did you try after removing .get(0)

Comment: @User6670 This Seems to work: = :CurrUserId  instead of = :UserInfo.getUserId() in the soql directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who bumps into this issue. It seems that you cannot use :UserInfo.getUserId() directly into soql. First create a variable and assign :UserInfo.getUserId() to the variable then use :variable in soql.

Comment: `CancelOptions = [SELECT Id, Reasons_Cancel__c from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()].get(0).Reasons_Cancel__c;` works for me as does `CancelOptions = [SELECT Id, Reasons_Cancel__c from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()][0].Reasons_Cancel__c;`